# How to implement a function to detect a loop using hittable approach in java

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

Problem:

I want to apply hashtable approach to detect a loop in java and I have implemented a method for it.

> Can anyone guide me is it correct or not?

Implementation:

```
public void detectLoop1()
{
    Node tnode = head;
    int i=0;
    //Initialize the HashTable
   Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
   //Traverse the list and while traversing if you find the address of 
   //the hittable is already in hashtable break the loop else insert the elements in hashtable.

   while (tnode != null)
    {
        System.out.print(tnode.data+"->");
        if(ht.contains(tnode)){
            System.out.println("Found a Loop");
            break;
        }
        ht.put(i, tnode);
        i++;
        tnode = tnode.next;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void detectLoop1()
{
    Node tnode = head;
    Set nodes = new HashSet();

   while (tnode != null)
    {
        System.out.print(tnode.data+"->");

        if(!nodes.add(tnode)){
            System.out.println("Found a Loop");
            break;
        }

        tnode = tnode.next;    
    }
}
```

Not sure how u can use `if(ht.contains(tnode))` when u put as key int `ht.put(i, tnode);`

Answer (score 0):

contains method of Hashtable class check the Value of object:

```
if(var4.value.equals(var1)) {
                    return true;
                }
```

so in this case , this implementation is correct, and it detected loop if it exist.